# Rails link to page not routing to where I want

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, capybara, erb, rspec-rails

I have a page I want to display that is not index, show, edit, etc. The page I want is `adoption.html.erb`, but for some reason it's grabbing the show page id. In my `views/shared/_header.html.erb` file, I have `<li><%= link_to "More About Dog Adoption", adoption_info_path, class: "dog-adopt-info" %></li>`. Which is supposed to go to here: `adoption.html.erb`, but is instead erring out with: `Couldn't find Dog with 'id'=adoption`. I'm really stuck and not sure why it's grabbing the id from show. Thoughts? P.S. Let me know if you need more information.

```
class DogsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @dogs = Dog.all
  end

  def show
    @dog = Dog.find(params[:id])
  end

  def adoption
  end

end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :dogs, only: [:index, :show]
get "dogs/adoption", as: "adoption_info"
```

app/views/shared/_header.html.erb

```
 <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About Dog Adoption</a>
 <ul class="about-dog-adoption">
   <li><%= link_to "More About Dog Adoption", adoption_info_path, class: "dog-adopt-info" %></li>
 </ul>
```

When I click on the above link it errors with:[image]

My rspec test passes which seems like a false positive:

```
context "#dogs_adoption" do
  it "renders more info about dog adoptions" do
     get :adoption
     expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code:

```
get "dogs/adoption", as: "adoption_info"
resources :dogs, only: [:index, :show]
```

Problem: your routes "/dogs/adoption" goes to dogs controller with show as action with id: "adoption".

Comment: That was easy haha. So with routes, order matters. I just now remember running into something similar almost a year ago. Thank you, @puneet18!